# How to apply filter in VS 2012 in Server Explorer stored procedures?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, orm

[image]

I have a funny problem. I can't get my stored procedure in the Server Explorer and push it into my ORM designer. I can't because in my database there are around 100.000 procedures and while VS 2012 does not load the whole procedures, Server Explorer is not responding.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: you need some extension to VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need some extensions(Productivity Power Tools) to do your job : go [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) and get the extension.

That will add a new "Solution Navigator" tabbed control, from which you can make a "GLOBAL" text search to your solution.

It will show you everything that matches the partial entered text (xml files, cs files, classes, methods, etc).

That is very close to what you need.